# Please correct the use of the word

Tags: meaning

Superfluous

My family is not superfluous to me.
Is my presence here getting to be superfluous ?

Do the above sentences make sense ?

Comment: Could you give us the context in which these sentences are being said?

Comment: Is my presence here getting to be superfluous ? This sentence said by a person who feels that his presence is getting a bit unwanted by others. So he thinks that others do not want him to be there.

Comment: Okay. Yes, that sentence makes sense, but there might be a better way to say it. Will add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the given context, yes, that sentence does make sense.

However, it does sound a little formal and stilted, so perhaps try asking, for example, "Am I still needed here?" or "Is my presence still required?" or "Should I start heading off?".